# how to get data from Intent Activity and button activated in ListView

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

Hi thanks for reading this! Please help me.

I am trying to create a restaurant app which the display 3 buttons in the menu then click the food button which display the list of food, then customer can choose the food they want to order then send back the order back to first page. I read a lot of the article and some say use the listview.setItemsCanFocus(true) but I having problem to understand it to implement it. and some say the button listener inside the getView but when I implement my program just hang. Please help me. Thank you.

my menu :

[image]

here is my food(second) page

[image]

I am having problems:

1. To transfer the array of selected data(food order) back from the food.class back to my main class which is restaurant.class
2. After I add the button in the list the food is not clickable(the whole row of food).
3. click on the image to enlarge and other places(besides image to dismiss it)

my main class(restaurant)

```
public class SesameRestaurant extends Activity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}


public void foodMenu(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(SesameRestaurant.this,Food.class));

    //setContentView(R.layout.foods);
}

public void drinkMenu(View v){startActivity(new Intent(SesameRestaurant.this,Drink.class));}
public void billMenu(View v){}
```

}

my second class (food.class)

```
package com.restaurant.sesame;

 public class Food extends ListActivity {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd; 


static final String[] title = new String[] {
            "Cow Rib steak", 
            "Thai Prawn Fried Rice",    
            "Christmas Sensation Delight",
            "Salmon Steak"      };

static final String[] detail = new String[] {
                "1h 37m Shipping: $10.00",
                "1h 39m Shipping: Free",
                "58m 6s Shipping: $10.00",
                "59m 30s Shipping: $10.95"  };

private Integer [] imgid = { R.drawable.food1, R.drawable.food2, R.drawable.food3, R.drawable.food4 };


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.foods);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
            Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            data = new Vector<RowData>();
            for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
            try {
                rd = new RowData(i,title[i],detail[i]);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
               data.add(rd);
            }
               CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list, R.id.title, data);
               setListAdapter(adapter);
               getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}

 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {          
     Log.w("my app", "Click list Item!!!"); 
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected "+(position+1)+"th item",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

 public void orderClick(View v){


 }

 private class RowData {
        protected int mId;
        protected String mTitle;
        protected String mDetail;

     RowData(int id,String title,String detail)
     {
                mId=id;
                mTitle = title;
                mDetail=detail;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return mId+" "+mTitle+" "+mDetail;
     }
 }

 private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
     public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {               
         super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
         ViewHolder holder = null;
         TextView title = null;
         TextView detail = null;
         ImageView i11=null;
         RowData rowData= getItem(position);
         if(null == convertView){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
         }
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         title = holder.gettitle();
         title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
         detail = holder.getdetail();
         detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);                                                     
         i11=holder.getImage();
         i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);


         return convertView;
     }

     private class ViewHolder {
         private View mRow;
         private TextView title = null;
         private TextView detail = null;
         private ImageView i11=null; 
         public ViewHolder(View row) {
             mRow = row;
         }

         public TextView gettitle() {
             if(null == title){
                 title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
             }
             return title;
         }     

         public TextView getdetail() {
             if(null == detail){
                 detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
             }
             return detail;
         }
         public ImageView getImage() {
             if(null == i11){
                 i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
             }
             return i11;
         }
     }
 }


 public void backClick(View v){
    finish(); 
 }
```

}

my food menu interface foods.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Button  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Back"  
        android:onClick="backClick"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
</Button>
```

my list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/img"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quantity :"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quantityInput"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quantity"
                android:hint="1-10"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/order"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quantity"
                android:onClick="orderClick"
                android:text="Order"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To transfer data back you can start the food.class activity with:

```
startActivityForResult();
```

putting data back in the intent using:

```
getIntent().putExtra()
```

As for the ListView problem with items being unclickable... there are a lot of "answers" out there, but the most simple is to set all of your widgets in each row so the properties have

```
android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: More information is available at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html under the section towards the top titled "Starting Activities and Getting Results"

Comment: I am confused that where should I put 
android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"?

Comment: The XML for each widget in your row's layout.

Comment: If I added to all widgets(does it need to include Linearlayout?), my edittext become uneditable and my button also unclickable.